# Request select retornando valor nulo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, request

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldades em pegar o valor de um select no formulário a seguir:

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'FilterController@EstatisticaEsic', 'class' => 'form-filter'))}}
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divEstatic-3">
               {{Form::label('mesEsic', 'Selecione o mês')}} 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divEstatic-4 selectEstatic">
                {{Form::select('mesEsic', array('0' => 'Selecione', '01' => 'Janeiro', '02' => 'Fevereiro',
                            '03' => 'Março', '04' => 'Abril', '05' => 'Maio', '06' => 'Junho', '07' => 'Julho',
                            '08' => 'Agosto', '09' => 'Setembro', '10' => 'Outubro', '11' => 'Novembro',
                            '12' => 'Dezembro'), null, ['class' => 'form-control estaticForm'])}}


        {{Form::submit('Visualizar', ['class' => 'btn btn-info btnEstatic'])}}
    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
```

Feito isso, criei a rota:

```
Route::post('/EstatisticaEsic', 'FilterController@EstatisticaEsic');
```

E o metodo no controller:

```
public function EstatisticaEsic(Request $request)
    {
//        $mes = ($request->mesEsic ? $request->mesEsic : 0);
//        $mes = Input::get('mesEsic');
        $mes = $request->input('mesEsic');

        $table = DB::table('pedido_esic')
//                ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTR(created_at, 6, 2)"), '=', $mes)
                ->select(DB::raw("(Select count(id) from pedido_esic) as a"), 
                        DB::raw("(Select count(id) from pedido_esic where situacao = 'Respondido') as b"),
                        DB::raw("(Select count(id) from pedido_esic where situacao = 'Em Tramitação') as c"))
                ->get();


//        return $mes;
        return ['table' => $table[0], 'mes' => $mes];
    }
```

Então criei uma função no javascript pegando o objeto da rota e preenchendo determinadas divs:

```
$(function (){
    $('.btnEstatic').on('click', function (event){

        event.preventDefault();

//        $.post($(this).attr('href'))
            $.post('../public/EstatisticaEsic')
                .done(function (json){
                console.log(json.mes);
                        $('.divEstaticRegis').html('');
                        $('.divEstaticResp').html('');
                        $('.divEstaticIndef').html('');

                        $('.divEstaticRegis').html(json.table.a);
                        $('.divEstaticResp').html(json.table.b);
                        $('.divEstaticIndef').html(json.table.c);
                }).error(function (json){console.log(json);
                $('body').html(json.responseText);});
    });
});
```

O problema é que meu select no formulário não corresponde como deveria, o retorno dele só fica como "null" tentei, tentei e não tive sucesso, quando eu mando retornar a variável $mes pelo próprio controller me retorna corretamente, mas se eu jogo ela dentro da pesquisa do banco de dados ou como objeto no java script o retorno é sempre "null", alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? No que estou errando?

Comment: Em `EstatisticaEsic` vc não teria que dar um `echo json_encode(['table' => $table[0], 'mes' => $mes])` no lugar do return ?

Comment: Não entendi onde eu uso o que você citou, mas acredito que não é necessário, já que aparentemente meu problema é apenas o por que meu $request->mesEsic não está funcionando no controller quando eu utulizo dentro da query sql.

Comment: O @rray tem razão, acho que é daí que o erro vem, contudo em laravel é mais complexo que isso, deve enviar o token também no ajax, e depois no lado servidor faz: `return response()->json(['table' => $table[0], 'mes' => $mes]);` e depois no ajax deve fazer o decode da resposta `var dados = JSON.parse(json);` que vai dar um obj de JS e pode aceder assim: `dados.mes;`. Aqui estão algumas referências: http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/csrf-protection-with-ajax-and-laravel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request